# Notation: is it correct to write $x \succsim y \succsim z$ before using transitivity?

Tags: microeconomics

Let $\succsim$ complete and $x, y, z \in X$. Suppose $x \succsim y$ and $y \succsim z$. Is it OK to write $x \succsim y \succsim z$ just knowing this?

Or, on the contrary, such expression automatically implies $x \succsim z$?

Comment: This seems more like a math question. (Math notation specifically, so very little microeconomics is involved.) Also, it boils down to whether writing
$$
5 > 2 < 3
$$
is okay. These are two different inequalities, but I was lazy and did not write the symbol 2 again. But this clearly does not imply anything about the relationship of 5 and 3.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\succsim$ symbolizes a ***binary*** relation, and so should be used as one. Writing "$x\succsim y\succsim z$" as a shorthand for "$x\succsim y$ and $y\succsim z$" is an abuse of notation and should only be used within an appropriate context where confusion/misinterpretation is unlikely.

Comment: To be clear, you can't conclude that $x \succsim z$ without assuming transitivity.